# How to complete sidebar menu?

Tags: javascript, menu, jquery-selectors, sidebar

I'm having trouble trying to complete my sidebar menu. Right now the contents are showing directly under the header instead of showing when the menu tab is clicked. Also the close menu button is wrapped in  tag but it doesn't seem to do anything right now. I can figure out the transition for the sidebar but my issue is getting the contents to show when the button near the header is clicked. I thought using query selector would automatically make it display a sidebar menu. Please let me know what I'm missing.

**App.js:**

```
import fzero from './image/fzero.jpg';
import sonic from './image/sonic.jpg';
import retail from './image/retail.jpg';
import mark from './image/mark.jpg';
import heli from './image/heli.png';
import team from './image/team.png';
import tiger from './image/tiger.png';
import mario from './image/mario.jpg';
import './index.css';

function App() {

  const openMenu = () =>{
    document.querySelector('.sidebar').classList.add('open')
  }

  const closeMenu = () =>{
    document.querySelector('.sidebar').classList.remove('open')
  }


  return (
<div className="App"> 
  <body>
    <header>
      <div className='head1'>
        <div className='dropdown'>
          <button onClick={openMenu}>&#9776;</button>

        </div>

        <h1>GameShop</h1>
      </div>
    </header>

    <aside className="sidebar">
      <h3>Extras</h3>
      <button className="side-close" onClick={closeMenu}>X</button>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">Accessories</a>
        </li>

        <li>
        <a href="index.html">Pre-orders</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
    
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='prod'>
          <img src={fzero} className="fzero" alt="logo" />
          <div className='item'>
            <a className="cover" href="">
              F-zero 
            </a>

            <div className='system'>
              <p>Nintendo Switch</p>
            </div>

            <div className="price">
              <p>$59.99</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='prod'>
          <img src={sonic} className="sonic" alt="logo" />
          <div className='item'>
            <a className="cover" href="">
              Sonic Earth
            </a>

            <div className='system'>
              <p>Playstation</p>
            </div>

            <div className='price'>
              <p>$49.99</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='prod'>
          <img src={retail} className="retail" alt="logo" />
          <div className='item'>
            <a className="cover" href="">
              Retail Manager 13
            </a>

            <div className='system'>
              <p>PC</p>
            </div>

            <div className='price'>
              <p>$12.99</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='prod'>
          <img src={mark} className="mark" alt="logo" />
          <div className='item'>
            <a className="cover" href="">
              Mark Zuckerberg's Pro Surfer
            </a>

            <div className='system'>
              <p>Xbox</p>
            </div>
            
            <div className='price'>
              <p>$39.99</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>

        <div className='prod'>
          <img src={mario} className="mario" alt="logo" />
          <div className='item'>
            <a className="cover" href="">
              Super Mario Maker Deluxe 
            </a>

            <div className='system'>
              <p>Nintendo Switch</p>
            </div>

            <div className="price">
              <p>$59.99</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='prod'>
          <img src={heli} className="heli" alt="logo" />
          <div className='item'>
            <a className="cover" href="">
              Planet of the Helicopter in Africa 
            </a>

            <div className='system'>
              <p>PC</p>
            </div>

            <div className="price">
              <p>$12.99</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='prod'>
          <img src={team} className="team" alt="logo" />
          <div className='item'>
            <a className="cover" href="">
              Team Fortress 2.5
            </a>

            <div className='system'>
              <p>Xbox</p>
            </div>

            <div className="price">
              <p>$39.99</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div className='prod'>
          <img src={tiger} className="tiger" alt="logo" />
          <div className='item'>
            <a className="cover" href="">
              Tiger Woods Driving Simulator 
            </a>

            <div className='system'>
              <p>Playstation</p>
            </div>

            <div className="price">
              <p>$49.99</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        
        
      </div>

  </body>
</div>


);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you using Reactjs? If you are using Reactjs, you don't really need to manipulate the DOM directly using `document.querySelector('.sidebar').classList.add('open')`. You have provided no CSS in above code, so we don't know what happens when `open` class is added. Can you create a https://codesandbox.io/ to reprocude your issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your CSS looks like but here is way you can implement what you want.

<sup>**Note:** Assuming you are using **React.js**</sup>

**Final Code:**

[**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-night-vw922?file=/src/styles.css)

**index.css**

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  display: none;
  /* Just for styling */
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.sidebar.open {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  /* Just for styling */
  text-align: center;
}
```

**App.js**

```js
import fzero from './image/fzero.jpg';
import sonic from './image/sonic.jpg';
import retail from './image/retail.jpg';
import mark from './image/mark.jpg';
import heli from './image/heli.png';
import team from './image/team.png';
import tiger from './image/tiger.png';
import mario from './image/mario.jpg';
import './index.css';

function App() {
  const openMenu = () => {
    document.querySelector(".sidebar").classList.add("open");
  };

  const closeMenu = () => {
    document.querySelector(".sidebar").classList.remove("open");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <body>
        <header>
          <div className="head1">
            <div className="dropdown">
              <button onClick={openMenu}>&#9776;</button>
            </div>

            <h1>GameShop</h1>
          </div>
        </header>

        <div className="wrapper">
          <aside className="sidebar">
            <h3>Extras</h3>
            <button className="side-close" onClick={closeMenu}>
              X
            </button>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="index.html">Accessories</a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="index.html">Pre-orders</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </aside>

          <div className="container">
            <div className="prod">
              <img src={fzero} className="fzero" alt="logo" />
              <div className="item">
                <a className="cover" href="">
                  F-zero
                </a>

                <div className="system">
                  <p>Nintendo Switch</p>
                </div>

                <div className="price">
                  <p>$59.99</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="prod">
              <img src={sonic} className="sonic" alt="logo" />
              <div className="item">
                <a className="cover" href="">
                  Sonic Earth
                </a>

                <div className="system">
                  <p>Playstation</p>
                </div>

                <div className="price">
                  <p>$49.99</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="prod">
              <img src={retail} className="retail" alt="logo" />
              <div className="item">
                <a className="cover" href="">
                  Retail Manager 13
                </a>

                <div className="system">
                  <p>PC</p>
                </div>

                <div className="price">
                  <p>$12.99</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="prod">
              <img src={mark} className="mark" alt="logo" />
              <div className="item">
                <a className="cover" href="">
                  Mark Zuckerberg's Pro Surfer
                </a>

                <div className="system">
                  <p>Xbox</p>
                </div>

                <div className="price">
                  <p>$39.99</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="prod">
              <img src={mario} className="mario" alt="logo" />
              <div className="item">
                <a className="cover" href="">
                  Super Mario Maker Deluxe
                </a>

                <div className="system">
                  <p>Nintendo Switch</p>
                </div>

                <div className="price">
                  <p>$59.99</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="prod">
              <img src={heli} className="heli" alt="logo" />
              <div className="item">
                <a className="cover" href="">
                  Planet of the Helicopter in Africa
                </a>

                <div className="system">
                  <p>PC</p>
                </div>

                <div className="price">
                  <p>$12.99</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="prod">
              <img src={team} className="team" alt="logo" />
              <div className="item">
                <a className="cover" href="">
                  Team Fortress 2.5
                </a>

                <div className="system">
                  <p>Xbox</p>
                </div>

                <div className="price">
                  <p>$39.99</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="prod">
              <img src={tiger} className="tiger" alt="logo" />
              <div className="item">
                <a className="cover" href="">
                  Tiger Woods Driving Simulator
                </a>

                <div className="system">
                  <p>Playstation</p>
                </div>

                <div className="price">
                  <p>$49.99</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you I got it to display just fine